# Which trainers in Match Call are always unavailable for battle?

Tags: pokemon-third-generation, pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

In Pokemon Emerald, a PokeNav feature called Match Call was added that allows you to keep track of certain NPC trainers and see whether or not they're available for a rematch. The trainers who are available for rematch at the moment have a tiny Pokeball icon next to their name:

[image: Match Call]

Battling with these trainers will remove the icon from next to their name. It seems like only a finite number can be available for rematch at any given time, so it's necessary to battle some of them in order for others to become available.

I know that trainers who are not or cannot be registered typically cannot be battled again, but it seems like some trainers registered on Match Call, such as Young Couple Kira & Dan in the Abandoned Ship, are *never* available for a rematch. Others, like Triathlete Abigail on Cycling Road, *are* sometimes available. Is there anything that can be done to rematch trainers like Kira & Dan? If not, which trainers that are registered on Match Call will never be available for further battle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look up these regions on Bulbapedia, it says they do offer several rematches.

Possible explanation for this (also from [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9Nav)):

> The more often the player steps in an area that includes a Trainer that can be rematched, the more likely each Trainer in that area is going to be ready for a rematch.

So if you never go near these areas, your chances of getting rematches from trainers there are slim.

Comment: I thought this was incorrect at first, but I was only walking (well, surfing) in the general _area_ of the Abandoned Ship. Since I actually entered it and walked around, I was able to rematch the trainers there that I was never able to match with before.